# Using grep to count total number of occurrences and output found line

Tags: bash, grep

I am using `grep` tool inside a Bash loop to count the number of found unique values inside the population but I would also like to output the found line.

Currently I am running the following command inside my loop:

```
n=$(grep -o -i ${uniqueVal} ${population} | wc -l)
total+=n
```

This however only outputs the number of occurrences found it does not output the matched line. Is there a way to count the number of occurrences while outputting only the matches to the screen?

uniqueVal

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
```

population

```
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.88
192.168.1.77
192.168.1.72
192.168.1.66
192.168.1.55
192.168.1.32
192.168.1.22
192.168.1.24
192.168.1.98
192.168.1.99
```

Output `Total Unique Found: 2`

I want the Desired Output to display the line in `population` that was found and then the total number found.

```
Found: 192.168.1.4
Found: 192.168.1.1
Total Unique Found: 2
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data, sample query and expected output. Furthermore, don't post them as comment or images but edit them to the original question. Thanks

Comment: remove the `-o` option then to count the matched lines. and don't assign the result to variable or count by the `wc -l` to see output on the Terminal

Comment: How would I still keep track of the total amount found without having to manually count each occurrence based on the output?

Comment: @Jav_Py see my answer, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add -ne flag to get the line number, along with `tee /dev/stderr` to print the resulting output

```
grep -o -i ${uniqueVal} ${population} -ne | tee /dev/stderr | wc -l
```

If you want to print the lines with `${population}` inside `${population}` file, along with the number of lines founds, then I would use `awk`, you can use the following:

```
awk '/${population}/' ${uniqueVal} | tee /dev/stderr | wc -l
```

Comment: it was just `-n` but I am looking to output the line not line number if there is a way to do that in a single grep line?

Comment: Neat, never thought about `tee /dev/stderr/` to print and process the output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `uniqueVal` and `population` are files:

```
join uniqueVal population | sed 's/.*/Found: &/' | tee /dev/stderr | wc -l
```

or f they are variables:

```
join <(echo $uniqueVal) <(echo $population) | sed 's/.*/Found: &/' | tee /dev/stderr | wc -l
```